# Replace string in multiple files with Vim using sed command

Tags: vim

I want to replace old by new string by using call:Rep(new,old) . So my pseudo code is  like this...

I am new to vimscript , I don't know how to do it.

```
function! Rep(old,new)
   !sed -i.bak 's/#{old}/#{new}/g' *
endfunction
```

Do you have any idea? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function to

```
function! Rep(old,new)
   exe "!sed -i.bak 's/".a:old."/".a:new."/g' *"
endfunction
```

then use `:call Rep(old,new)`. You can also create a command for it.

```
command! -nargs=+ Rep call Rep(<args>)
```

so that you can do `:Rep old new`.